# How to interpret this CDF (cumulative distribution function) graph

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am currently trying to interpret [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgymu.jpg) graph of the CDF based on remaining energy of nodes. I currently do not know how best to interpret this graph in terms of which of the two graphs is better with respect remaining energy. I would appreciate insights into explaining the graph.

Comment: I think the algorithm B graph would have fatter tails leading to non-robust statistics, I think it would be wiser to use algorithm A in general. But you need to elaborate the undergoing process in order to determine which method should be preffered.

Comment: It seems like the support of $A$ is $[0, 1.4]$ while the support of $B$ is $[0, 2]$. By looking at the slope of the ECDF, both looks like a unimodal distribution with mode around $[0.3, 0.4]$ and $[1.4, 1.5]$ respectively. And as said above, not sure what objective/quantity you are looking for. If you look at the area above the curve, below $1$, you can obtain the mean also. At last you may notice there is a jump at $0$, if this is not an estimation error, then there are some discrete point mass on $0$ with both ECDF - with $A$ has a higher (nearly double) probability of that.

Comment: The _reliability function_ $R_X(t) = 1 - F_X(t) = P(X > t)$ is sometimes used in reliability theory and survival analysis to emphasize the probability that a a component or individual survives beyond time $t.$ The reliability function is a monotone non-decreasing curve.

Comment: Thanks all for reply

Comment: Thanks all for reply, actually am trying to balance the energy usage in the network, where 800 nodes in that network are powered with 2J at the beginning. So after some round (tasks), I calculate the remaining energy for each node for both algorithms and see which one is more balancing in energy usage.